# Given $\angle A = 60°, \angle B = 80°, \angle C = 40°$, find $\alpha$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

[image]

I tried making an equilateral triangle with side $b$ but it didn't seem to be of any use. Please help.

Comment: Can you use trigonometry? If so, this problem becomes pretty simple.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

- Construct $BC=AC=a+b+c$
- Mark $EF=ED=c$. So $FB=b$
- $\triangle DEF$ is $100^{\circ}-40^{\circ}-40^{\circ}$ triangle, so is $\triangle CDF$
- $CD=DF=b=FB$.
- $\angle BFD=140^{\circ} \Rightarrow \angle FBD = \angle FDB = 20^{\circ}$
- In $\triangle ACD$, $$ \dfrac{b}{\sin \alpha} = \dfrac{a+b+c}{\sin 60^{\circ}}$$
  In $\triangle BCD$, $$ \dfrac{b}{\sin 20^{\circ}} = \dfrac{a+b+c}{\sin 120^{\circ}}$$
  We conclude $$ \boxed{\alpha = 20^{\circ}}$$

---

Thanks to @Nanayajitzuki, we can also finish without resorting to sine law.

[image]

- Construct equilateral $\triangle GCD$ with $G$ on $AD$.
- In $\triangle CGA$ and $\triangle CDB$, $\angle CGA = 120^{\circ} = \angle CDB$ . $CD=b=CG$. $CA=CB$.
- So $\triangle CGA \cong \triangle CDB$ by **SSA congruence condition**** $$\boxed{\therefore \alpha = 20^{\circ}}$$

**Note****

The ambiguity in SSA congruence condition arises only when involved angle is acute (it leads to precisely two possible triangles as shown below $\triangle ABD$ and  $\triangle ABE$). If obtuse angle is involved, there is no ambiguity. So its use here is justified.

[image]

Comment: I think it's possible to have a direct prove without sine law, spot a point $G$ on $AD$ making $\triangle CDG$ equilateral. $\angle AGC=\angle BDC=120$ and they are both obtuse angle, so $\triangle AGC\cong\triangle BDC$, which is tricky since the congruence only holds for obtuse angle like this case.

Comment: Nice @Nanayajitzuki, got it! Editing.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : you need a calculator and the law of sines.

You can express both b and c in terms of a, via the law of sines.

then, you can use the law of sines again on the left hand triangle re 
100 degrees -> (a + b + c) and $\alpha$ -> a.